# ajax not work on firefox but works on chrome

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

i am trying to insert to database using ajax. it works on chrome but does work on firefox. pls i need your help.here is my code

i got these on the console

```
Use of inputEncoding is deprecated.

 FormData { }
```

This my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.comment-block').load('connection/profile_comment.php');
$("#pcom").on('submit', function(e){    
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var myForm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    console.warn(myForm);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'connection/profile_comment.php',
        data : new FormData($(this)[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").show().fadeOut(5000);
        },
        success: function(data){
            //$('.comment-block').load('connection/profile_comment.php');
            console.log(data);
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
            $("#pcom").find("#profile_comment").val("");
            $('.comment-block').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
});
});
```

and connection/profile_comment.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['pcomment']))
    {
    $comment=$_POST['profile_comment'];
    $student_id=$_POST['student_id'];
    $sendcomment=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO profile_comment (student_id,  commenter_id, comment) VALUES (:student_id,:commenter_id,:comment)");
    $sendcomment->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
    $sendcomment->bindParam(':commenter_id', $user_id);
    $sendcomment->bindParam(':comment', $comment);
    $sendcomment->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the console errors if any

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: *First line of function* `return false;`

Comment: I guess it works on chrome because you forget to clear browser cache

Answer (score 2):

First fix this:

```
$("#pcom").on('submit', function(){ 
    return false;
```

To this:

```
$("#pcom").on('submit', function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
```

If doesn't work, add this next to last code (before $.ajax(... ):

```
var myForm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
console.warn(myForm);
```

And tell us what is showed on console

Comment: i tried all you said but i got these on the console  `Use of inputEncoding is deprecated.`
`FormData {  }`